# Bounded family and uniform convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the disk of the complex plane, 
assume that $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of holomorphic functions on $D$, 
if $\{f_n\}$ converge in a infinite compact subset of $D$, 
do it implies that the limit function is well-defined and holomorphic on $D$?